# Extracting data from link changes language on retrieval

Tags: java, regex, http, proxy

So I'm trying to extract some data from IMDB from this link:

http://www.imdb.com/find?q=sleepers&s=all ***(Look at source code)***

So with this regex:

```
(?s:<td class=\"result_text\"> <a href=\"/title/.*?</td>)
```

And then this:

```
(?s:(?i:(?<=[>])Sleepers.*?(?=</td>)))
```

I can extract all matching titles that contains the word Sleepers... and this is where the problem arises:

Because I'm from a different country, the first match for "Sleepers" changes to "Los hijos de la calle" like so:

```
<td class="result_text"> <a href="/title/tt0117665/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1" >Los hijos de la calle</a> (1996) <br/>aka <i>"Sleepers"</i> </td>
```

Is there a way I can force an http connection made from Java so this doesn't happen???

I didn't have this problem when I was using HTMLUnit, but it's very slow for the type of thing i'm doing.

I'm using a proxy, but if I go through the browser, the page (source code) displays in english.

EDIT:

Setting the desired language through setRequestHeader() solved the problem:

```
conn = url.openConnection(proxy);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US");

>> FOUND: <td class="result_text"> <a href="/title/tt0117665/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1" >Sleepers</a> (1996) </td>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to add an Accept-Language http header to your request. If that doesn't solve the problem, you can try copying whatever cookies the browser is sending.
If you use chromium or chrome, open developer tools (F12) and go to the network tab to see exactly what headers and cookies are being sent. You can also get that info in firefox if you use firebug.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem! I'm updating the results in the question.